# How to alter number of repetitions in while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

i have one php page in which I have two  loops in place. this loop is used to retrieve data from database column and print in the form of a row group by stud_no column.

here is a code:

```
<?php  
     $link=mysql_connect("localhost","xyz","toor") or die("Cannot Connect to the database!");
     mysql_select_db("dbase",$link) or die ("Cannot select the database!");
     $query2="SELECT stud_no FROM fees_master ORDER BY stud_no  ;";
     $resource2=mysql_query($query2,$link);

     $i=1;
     while($res=mysql_fetch_array($resource2)) {
        $lsd=$res[0];
        $query="SELECT stud_no,inst_amt FROM fees_master WHERE stud_no LIKE $lsd ;";

        $resource=mysql_query($query,$link);
        echo"<table align=\"center\" border=\"0.5\"> <tr>";

        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($resource)){ 

           echo "<td>".$i."</td>,";
           echo "<td>".$result[0].",</td>";
           echo "<td>".$result[1].",</td>,";
          if($result[0]!==$lsd)
          {
              echo"</tr></table>";
              break;
          }
        } 
}
?>
```

after running this code I am getting this output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLvE5.png

please help. I want to print each distinct line only once.

Comment: use leftjoin instead.

Comment: but how i am new to this can you help me to write it.

Comment: basically what are you trying to do? what are your tables? how are they designed? can you give sample records and the desired output?

Comment: there is a link to image. that out put is my current output. i want to print distinct line only once, but as you can see that code is reapeting that line several times..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change $query2 as below

```
$query2="SELECT DISTINCT stud_no FROM fees_master ORDER BY stud_no  ;";
```